# Is it correct to say "What's the happened?"?

Tags: questions

I would say just "What happened?", but I've heard this also.

Comment: Are you sure it's not "What the *bleep* happened?", with "bleep" kind of swallowed?

Answer (score 2):

**No.** The reason is that "happened" is not a noun, it is the past tense of a verb. Verbs do not take the definite article "the."

Some proper ways to express the question:

> What happened?
>
> What has happened?
>
> What's happened?

The last one is a contraction of "What has happened?"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were thinking of something like "What the [*missing word*] happened"

You can build a sentence in this way if you use a noun instead of a missing word.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: What the heck happened.

Comment: In that case could you edit your answer to "What the [missing word] happened?"

Comment: sorry, it was a typo